# Take fft and ifft for a few specific frequencies

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a question regarding to the `fft` and `ifft` functions.

Suppose `A` is an array that includes 365 days of data:

```
fft_output = scipy.fftpack.fft(A)
```

It gives me the coefficients related to all frequencies. I only need three frequencies `(0, 1/365, 1/182)`. So I think `fft_output[0]` and `fft_output[364]`, `fft_output[181]` would be correct option for my desired frequencies.

Now I would like to take `ifft` just by using these three frequencies for 365 days. I didn't figure out how can I do this by using the `ifft` function.

I would appreciate if anyone guides me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used the following code to calculate the annual cycle of my data. Hopefully, it gave me the correct answer.

```
Amp = scipy.fftpack.fft(A)

F = np.zeros(365)

F = F.tolist()

F[0] = Amp[0]

F[1] = Amp[1]

F[364] = Amp[364]

ann_cycle = np.abs(np.fft.ifft(F))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but let me give it a try:

First, if you need the amplitudes of just a few components of the original signal, you can calculate them individually. If `A` is your data series, and you want to know just the `k`th bin, you can use the [definition of DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition):

```
x = np.sum(A*np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*k*np.arange(len(A))/len(A)))
```

Because the units of `k` are cycles/sample, the frequency corresponding to the `k`th bin is given by `k*F_s/len(A)`, where `F_s` is the sampling frequency of the signal `A` (e.g. Hz, m^-1, etc.).

The the corresponding IFFT bin is given by taking the negative of the exponent:

```
x = np.sum(A*np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*k*np.arange(len(A))/len(A)))
```

Next, assuming you've used the first equation above to calculate the three bins `x0`, `x181`, and `x364`, if you want to reconstruct the original signal, using just those values, you can do this:

```
F = np.zeros((365))
F[0] = x0
F[181] = x181
F[364] = x364
A2 = np.fft.ifft(F) # complex--you may wish to use np.abs(np.fft.ifft(F))
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. The last part was helpful. The other thing which I figured out was in order to select an specific frequency in my case 1/365, I have to select pair frequencies (positive and negative) except for zero frequency. Which means 1 and also 364 for my case.